# Weka java : how to change the attributes priorities?

Tags: java, statistics, regression, weka, data-mining

I am new at `weka` library. I don't know if it's possible to *customize the linear regression function*. In fact, I want the algorithm to consider a parameter more than the other ones.

In my situation, i have nominal attributes, and a numeric attribute to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Regression is the task of figuring out the *best* model.

It learns a weight for each variable (which can also be 0 or negative).

If you want to predefine weights, you have to implement your own variant of regression - it's not the usual linear regression anymore.

Comment: thanks , how can I implement my own variant of regression , do you have an example ?

Comment: No, I've never done so. Start with solving the math, on paper. You can't start coding, if you don't know what to do yet. I think you'll find out your idea doesn't work, if you look at the math.